# Error run on IOS emulator after update to IOS 11 - Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ios-simulator, ionic3

After update to IOS 11, command

> ionic cordova run ios -lc --target="iPhone-6"

I have error

> ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
>
> No available runtimes could be found for "iPhone 6". [ERROR] An error
>   occurred while running cordova run ios --target iPhone-6 (exit code
>   1).

Simulators list after command

> ios-sim showdevicetypes

```
Apple-TV-1080p, tvOS 11.0
Apple-TV-4K-4K, tvOS 11.0
Apple-TV-4K-1080p, tvOS 11.0
Apple-Watch-38mm, watchOS 4.0
Apple-Watch-42mm, watchOS 4.0
Apple-Watch-Series-2-38mm, watchOS 4.0
Apple-Watch-Series-2-42mm, watchOS 4.0
Apple-Watch-Series-3-38mm, watchOS 4.0
Apple-Watch-Series-3-42mm, watchOS 4.0
iPhone-5s, 11.0
iPhone-6, 11.0
iPhone-6-Plus, 11.0
iPhone-6s, 11.0
iPhone-6s-Plus, 11.0
iPhone-7, 11.0
iPhone-7-Plus, 11.0
iPhone-SE, 11.0
iPhone-8, 11.0
iPhone-8-Plus, 11.0
iPhone-X, 11.0
iPad-Air, 11.0
iPad-Air-2, 11.0
iPad--5th-generation-, 11.0
iPad-Pro--9-7-inch-, 11.0
iPad-Pro, 11.0
iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---2nd-generation-, 11.0
iPad-Pro--10-5-inch-, 11.0
```

BUT after command

> cordova emulate ios --list

Simulators list is empty

```
Available iOS Simulators:
MacBook-Air-apple:Snaptofix2 apple$
```

Help, please.

Comment: Did you try to use any other device? Just to verify ...

Comment: Yes, I try to use iPhone-5s, iPhone-6s-Plus...same mistake. If I open project in Xcode, app is started normally

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is problem that you are using (or better say ionic) still old version of ios-sim npm package. As apple changed simulators in iOS 11 (and platform).

Solution is to use latest ios-sim (this is valid for 22.09.2017, next week should be release a official version). So this would be mean just update ios-sim package.

Today, you need to use "latest" version.

Like:

```
cd platforms/ios/cordova && npm install ios-sim@latest
```

Here is also open issue: https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim/issues/218

Other option is to upgrade the whole ios platform to a proper version (for iOS 11 you need at least 4.5.0):

```
cordova platform add ios@4.5.0
```

(Be careful to remove platform first!)

Comment: perfect solution, i was looking for the solution from last 2 Hours and finally i find it here. Thanks

Comment: Perfect answer, +1. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help. :)

Comment: `cd platforms/ios/cordova && npm install ios-sim@latest` worked like a charm

`cordova platform add ios@4.5.0` haven't worked alone

Comment: @andre.almeida: This is because you need to remove platform first.